# Is Solr Better than the normal RDBMS in case of searching normal queries i.e not full text search?

Tags: database, search, indexing, solr, nosql

I am developing a web application where I want to use Solr for search only and keep my data on another Database.
I will be having 2 databases: one Relational (Sql Server) and the other will be a copy of it on the NoSQL Solr database.
I'll be searching for specific fields in the solr documents e.g(by id,name,type and join queries) i.e **NOT full text search**.

I know Solr strength is in full text search by creating inverted index on the documents data, now i want to know does it also helps in my case by creating another type of index on my documents which make **normal searching faster than sql server index**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will help you.

You need to consider what is your requirement. What is your preference?

If you have the solr as another additional option which will be used for the searching the application data, you need to consider that you have to constantly update the solr. You will need additional infrastructure and all.

If the performance is your main criteria and you don't want to put any search load on your RDBMS then you can add the solr to your system. Also consider how big your data is in the RDBMS. Because RDBMS system are also enough strong to support searching data.

Considering all the above aspects you can take the decision.

Comment: Currently the data is not that large but after a while it'll be hundreds of millions of records to search for and a lot of joins statements.

Comment: Also for the constant update i'll either be using listeners in my code for the update and delete, or do a incremental import using the Slr Data Import handler, i still don't know which one is a better choice.

Comment: Ok i'll be using it. is there anything that i should modify to make solr handle indexing to this kind of queries? or is it done by default ?

Comment: You need to learn DIH feature of solr in order to full fill your requirement...where in you will fetching data from database and indexing the same to solr